# Modify python nltk.word_tokenize to exclude "#" as delimiter

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am using Python's NLTK library to tokenize my sentences.

If my code is

```
text = "C# billion dollars; we don't own an ounce C++"
print nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

I get this as my output

```
['C', '#', 'billion', 'dollars', ';', 'we', 'do', "n't", 'own', 'an', 'ounce', 'C++']
```

The symbols `;` , `.` , `#` are considered as delimiters. Is there a way to remove `#` from the set of delimiters like how `+` isn't a delimiter and thus `C++` appears as a single token?

I want my output to be

```
['C#', 'billion', 'dollars', ';', 'we', 'do', "n't", 'own', 'an', 'ounce', 'C++']
```

I want `C#` to be considered as one token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea: instead of altering how text is tokenized, just loop over the tokens and join every '#' with the preceding one.

```
txt = "C# billion dollars; we don't own an ounce C++"
tokens = word_tokenize(txt)

i_offset = 0
for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
    i -= i_offset
    if t == '#' and i > 0:
        left = tokens[:i-1]
        joined = [tokens[i - 1] + t]
        right = tokens[i + 1:]
        tokens = left + joined + right
        i_offset += 1

>>> tokens
['C#', 'billion', 'dollars', ';', 'we', 'do', "n't", 'own', 'an', 'ounce', 'C++']
```

Comment: A slight modification needs to be done. This is because in every iteration where we encounter `#`, the length of `tokens` reduces because we join 2 tokens.

Answer (score 6):

As dealing with multi-word tokenization, another way would be to retokenize the extracted tokens with NLTK [Multi-Word Expression tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html):

```
mwtokenizer = nltk.MWETokenizer(separator='')
mwtokenizer.add_mwe(('c', '#'))
mwtokenizer.tokenize(tokens)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

NLTK uses regular expressions to tokenize text, so you could use its regexp tokenizer to define your own regexp.

I'll create an example for you where text will be split on any space character (tab, new line, ecc) and a couple of other symbols just for instance:

```
>>> txt = "C# billion dollars; we don't own an ounce C++"
>>> regexp_tokenize(txt, pattern=r"\s|[\.,;']", gaps=True)
['C#', 'billion', 'dollars', 'we', 'don', 't', 'own', 'an', 'ounce', 'C++']
```

Comment: Note that the sentence is not correctly tokenized, if you want it to be you'll need a more complex expression. You can look at the [sorce code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk) for examples.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the source code for the function `word_tokenize`? I want to perform the same function as `word_tokenize` but, I want to remove `#` as one of the delimiters.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/develop/nltk/tokenize) is the folder where everything concerning tokenizers is, and that function in particular is at line 94 in file `__init__.py`. Unfortunately it is not using a regexp, but if you give me a sec I'll find out something better and edit this comment.

Comment: Check out the other (better) idea :)

Comment: Based on what the questioner desires to achive, the "gaps=True" should be removed.