# How to define special "untokenizable" words for nltk.word_tokenize

Tags: nltk, tokenize

I'm using `nltk.word_tokenize` for tokenizing some sentences which contain programming languages, frameworks, etc., which get incorrectly tokenized.

For example:

```
>>> tokenize.word_tokenize("I work with C#.")
['I', 'work', 'with', 'C', '#', '.']
```

Is there a way to enter a list of "exceptions" like this to the tokenizer? I already have compiled a list of all the things (languages, etc.) that I don't want to split.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify python nltk.word_tokenize to exclude “#” as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674103/modify-python-nltk-word-tokenize-to-exclude-as-delimiter)

Comment: The difference with that question is that OP is not asking to keep the `#` always, but instead just in `C#` and possibly in hundreds of other particular words such as `F#` and similar technical names.

Answer (score 4):

The [Multi Word Expression Tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=tokenize%20exception#module-nltk.tokenize.mwe) should be what you need.

You add the list of exceptions as tuples and pass it the already tokenized sentences:

```
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.MWETokenizer()
tokenizer.add_mwe(('C', '#'))
tokenizer.add_mwe(('F', '#'))
tokenizer.tokenize(['I', 'work', 'with', 'C', '#', '.'])
['I', 'work', 'with', 'C_#', '.']
tokenizer.tokenize(['I', 'work', 'with', 'F', '#', '.'])
['I', 'work', 'with', 'F_#', '.']
```