# how to prevent NLTK to split specifics words?

Tags: nltk

I have a list of stackoverflow tags : [javascript, node.js, c++, amazon-s3,....].

I want to tokenize a stackoverflow question : "what do I prefer ? javascript, node.js,  c++ or amazon-S3 ? This is dummy."

and I want nltk to tokenize 'node.js' into a single token : "node.js", not 'node' and 'js'.

How to tell nltk to not split a word if it is in my tag list ?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618528) possible duplicate, and the question seems to be the same, but the answer based on [Multi Word Expression Tokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=tokenize%20exception#module-nltk.tokenize.mwe) doesn't satisfy my need.

In fact if I use this solution, I think I'll have to reconstruct manually all tags, example :

```
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.MWETokenizer()
tokenizer.add_mwe('Python', '-', '3', '.', 'x)
```

My need is to keep all existing tags as "untokenizable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define special "untokenizable" words for nltk.word\_tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618528/how-to-define-special-untokenizable-words-for-nltk-word-tokenize)

Comment: thanks @Isaac, but I think it doesn't answer my need. I edtited my question for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the full range of tags that you're looking to retain as whole tokens, but it seems that NLTK's basic `word_tokenize()` function will preserve those particular items as tokens, without any tag list defined.

```
import nltk
sentence = "what do I prefer ? javascript, node.js, c++ or amazon-S3 ? This is dummy."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)
```

Output:

```
['what', 'do', 'I', 'prefer', '?', 'javascript', ',', 'node.js', ',', 'c++', 'or', 'amazon-S3', '?', 'This', 'is', 'dummy', '.']
```

Comment: yes, thanks @Isaac B. It seems that I not even tried it, as I was "sure" that it wasn't possible :(  . lesson learned. 
But I wonder how it is that NTLK handle this correctly, and where it is documented (I have searched but not found)