# Modify nltk.word_tokenize behaviour

Tags: python

I have some texts with some special tokens that correspond to specific "entities". Thy all start with the symbol `@`. For example, for indicating an age, the token `@AGE` is used.

The problem I am facing is that `nlkt.word_tokenize()` consider that special token as composed by two distinct tokens `@` and `AGE`:

As a simple example, consider:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
sentences = ["w1 w2 w3", "@NUM w2 w4", "@AGE w5 w1", "@CODE w1 w3"]
words = set(w for s in sentences for w in word_tokenize(s))
print(words)
```

whose output is:

```
{'@', 'w1', 'NUM', 'CODE', 'w4', 'w3', 'w5', 'w2', 'AGE'}
```

I could solve using a couple of answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674103/modify-python-nltk-word-tokenize-to-exclude-as-delimiter), but, since I do not like any of them for my specific case and two years have passed, I was wondering whether something new came up.

Is there anyone who knows if it is possible to instruct `word_tokenize` to exclude some special tokens from its default processing?